# Curious as to what CorA1 is and what it does?

Tags: organic-chemistry

First time Chemistry SE poster,

Was wondering what actually CorA1 is and what it actually does?

I ask because I found out I was allergic to a incredibly long list of items and this popped up to be a high allergen as I work through the list.

Google defines it as a: Magnesium transport protein CorA and it contributes to Ion transport?

Comment: Welcome to Chem SE. Feel free to take a [tour] of this site, so you'll have a better idea of who we are and how we run.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic (even though it has an accepted answer) because it's about the biological function of an enzyme, and is thus better asked at Biology.SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see, CorA and CorA1 are two different things. CorA is a protein, while CorA1 is the **gene that codes for that protein.**

It is the genes that when [translated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translation_(biology)) give rise to the protein.

This gene was isolated from the *Rhizobium meliloti*, a bacterium commonly known for forming leguminous nodules in [certain plants](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legume).

As for it's function, I'm not really a biologist, but I know that magnesium is a component of **chlorophyll** (It's coordinated at the center of the porphyrin complexes).

[image]

So you could say magnesium is rather important for plants. The $\ce{Mg^2+}$ ion needs to be transported from the soil to the leaves, and this protein facilitates this transport.

Comment: @RushRed Most welcome!